# Can't load firestore document data to variable in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to push a new screen to display the selected item's detail, when I get the data it fetches the document correctly, however if I try to set my object to use it in my screen it is undefined, but if I reload the app it does populate the object, here's the code:

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState();
    const getEvent = async (dbx) => {
        const eventDoc = doc(dbx, 'events', eventId);
        try {
            const eventSnapshot = await getDoc(eventDoc);
            if(eventSnapshot.exists()) {
                const fetchedEvent = eventSnapshot.data();
                setEvent(fetchedEvent);
                
            } else {
                console.log("Document does not exist")
            }
        
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        return;
      } 

    useEffect(
        ()=>{
            getEvent(db)
            console.log("Event Here: ", event);
        }
    ,[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable in the state is an asynchronous operation. In fact, so is loading data from Firestore, so neither of those operations is done by the time your `console.log("Event Here: ", event)` runs.

If you want to log the event value, use another effect that depends on that state variable to do so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log("Event Here: ", event);
},[event])
```

Comment: Your response made me revisit the Hooks topic in the documentation and I could find my answer, so as much as it's not the answer it was really helpful, thank you.

Comment: There's a button to the left of each answer to indicate that it was useful. ;-) --- If you solved your problem in a different way, consider posting a self-answer with that too, so other can benefit from it going forward.